# Member var initialization not working in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a class like:

```
class MyBlurredImageView: UIView {
    var myProp: Bool = true
    var blurEffectEnabled: Bool = true

    // ...
}
```

and a subclass like:

```
class MyOtherImageView: MyBlurredImageView {
    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere I use that subclass:

```
class MomentBookendCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myOtherImageView: MyOtherImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        myOtherImageView.myProp = false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

But the line

```
myOtherImageView.myProp = false;
```

...crashes with an exception. When I debug and inspect it, myOtherImageView seems to be allocated, but myProp is set to some unholy integer value like -122 -- it's never getting initialized.

Note that when I start to type `myImageView.blu`, Xcode autocompletes the rest of `blurEffectEnabled` -- it acknowledges that this is a property of myOtherImageView.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the storyboard had myOtherImageView linked to a regular UIImageView storyboard element -- the class type had changed in the code without updating the storyboard!

So somehow *some* of the right code was running, and some wasn't!